# Handling various message with IDialog

Tags: c#, botframework

Let's say you have a `ContactUsDialog`, `PizzaOrderDialog` as well as a `MyOrderDialog`. The user sends a message like: '*how far along is my pizza order*' - How would you know which dialog to start?

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity != null)
        {
            switch (activity.GetActivityType())
            {
                case ActivityTypes.Message:
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ContactUsDialg());
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new PizzaOrderDialog());
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MyOrderDialog());
                    break;
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
```

Comment: You can't do that. You need to decide which one is the root dialog and the in the root dialog re-route to others as needed.

Comment: I thought so... Can I use LUIS to accomplish this? Any examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in the way you are trying to. You need decide which one will be the root dialog and the re-route messages to other dialogs.

A few samples that might help you:

- [core-MultiDialogs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs): to understand how to call/forward messages to child dialogs
- [intelligence-LUIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS): to understand how to use LUIS

And yes, you can use LUIS as root dialog and then call child dialogs. Some posts that might help too:

- [LUIS / Bot Framework multiple dialog, move intent handling to another dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593904/luis-bot-framework-multiple-dialog-move-intent-handling-to-another-dialog)
- [How to forward from RootDialog to LuisDialog in Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464455/how-to-forward-from-rootdialog-to-luisdialog-in-bot-framework)
- [How does navigation work with LUIS subdialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077488/how-does-navigation-work-with-luis-subdialogs)